# Missing template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, serialization, boost

I know there have been similar questions here and elsewhere online regarding wrong 
initialization of template functions, but they don't show me what I am doing 
wrong.

I am trying to write some template functions to serialize `boost::multiarray` and
`boost::any` elements. My problem occurs when I try to call the `multiarray` template 
methods that have the following bodies:

**save_multi_array**

```
template<class Archive , typename T , std::size_t K>
inline void save_multi_array( Archive &ar , const boost::multi_array<T , K> &t ,
      const unsigned int file_version )
{
 typedef boost::multi_array<T , K> multi_array_;
 typedef typename multi_array_::size_type size_;

   for( int k = 0 ; k < K ; ++k ) {
     size_ nk = ( t.shape()[ k ] );
     ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( nk );
   }
  ar << boost::serialization::make_array( t.data() , t.num_elements() );
 }
```

**load_multi_array:**

```
 template<class Archive , typename T , std::size_t K>
 inline void load_multi_array( Archive &ar, boost::multi_array<T , K> &t ,
      const unsigned int file_version )

  {
  typedef boost::multi_array<T , K> multi_array_;
  typedef typename multi_array_::size_type size_;

  boost::array<size_ , K> extents;
  for( int k = 0 ; k < K ; ++k )
  ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP( extents[ k ] );

  t.resize( extents );
  ar >> make_array( t.data() , t.num_elements() );
  }
```

**serialize_array:**

```
 template<class Archive , typename T , int K>
 inline void serialize( Archive &ar , boost::multi_array<T , K> &t ,
                   const unsigned int file_version )
  {
    split_free( ar , t , file_version );
  }
```

Now, when I use this methods inside the `main.cpp` they work just fine, but when I try to call them inside the bodies of the template methods I wrote for the `boost::any` load and save I face problems. Here are the template methods for the `boost::any` part:

**save_any:**

```
 template<class T> struct un_any_type {};
 template<std::size_t K> struct un_any_int {};

 template<class Archive, typename T, std::size_t K>
 inline void save_any (Archive & ar, un_any_type<T>, un_any_int<K> , std::vector<boost::any>::const_iterator &it, const unsigned int file_version)
 {

  if(K == 0){
   if (it->type() ==typeid( T ) ) { //case of saving an object

     const std::type_info & ti = it->type();
     std::string a = ti.name();
     ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
     auto  var =  boost::any_cast< T >( *it );
     ar <<  (var);
    }//if

      if (it->type() ==typeid( T * ) ) { //case of saving a pointer of an object
       const std::type_info & ti = it->type();
       std::string a = ti.name();
       ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
       auto  var =  boost::any_cast< T * >( *it );
       ar <<  (*var);
      }//if
}//if for K-dim
else{

    if (it->type() ==typeid( boost::multi_array< T , K > ) ) { //case of saving a multi-dim array
               const std::type_info & ti = it->type();
               std::string a = ti.name();
               ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
               /*auto*/ boost::multi_array<T , K> var =  boost::any_cast< boost::multi_array<T , K> >( *it );
               save_multi_array ( ar , var , version );
             }//if

 }//if for K-dim
}
```

**load_any:**

```
 template<class Archive, typename T, std::size_t K>
 inline void load_any (Archive & ar, un_any_type<T>, un_any_int<K> , std::vector<boost::any>::iterator it, const unsigned int file_version)
 {

    if(K == 0){ // case we deal with object, pointer of object, etc

     T var;
      ar >>  (var);
     *it = var;
     }//if for K-dim
   else{

      if (it->type() ==typeid( boost::multi_array< T , K > ) ) { //case of saving a multi-dim array
        typedef boost::multi_array<T , K> array_type;
        array_type var;
        load_multi_array(ar, var, version);
     }//if

 }//if for K-dim
}
```

When I try to call `load_multi_array` and `save_multi_array` inside these methods I receive the error:

```
missing template arguments before ‘)’ token
```

****Edit based on the suggested comment:

So, first of all thank you for your interest.
To begin with here is the code I am running currently,
The main.cpp can be found in this link:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0464563914dd4b7508e54f199187d4f4

And the header file where I wrote the template functions can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0f19fdd16100c18244f90f488669640a

A bit further explanation of the code you can see in the above link,
The main.cpp has first all the proper includes (probably some are unnecessary, and after it I initialize the class gps_position where 
I include several type of elements that I want to check for serialization,
the difficult part is about the boost::multi array and the boost::any where I needed to write some piece of code to make them seriazable (the methods included in the header file).
As you can see there are two methods one for load and one for save because of the boost::any vector in order in the save method to save and pass the size of the vector and all the different types that are included in the boost::any vector.
So each if_case refers to an other type that is expected to exist inside the boost::any and for each of it we call the corresponding save_any or load_any template method to properly save or load the element in the boost::any vector. 
Now the problem itself lies in the fact that when inside the template methods of save_any & load_any I call the corresponding save_multi_array & load_multi_array inside the template methods in the header file more specifically:

**In line no. 88**:
                   save_multi_array ( ar , var ,version );

**In line no. 109**:
                   load_multi_array(ar, var, version);

I received the above mentioned error about the missing of template arguments. Finally what is printed in the console is the following thing:

```
  ../src/Multi_Array_Serialization.hpp: In function ‘void boost::serialization::save_any(Archive&, boost::serialization::un_any_type<T>, boost::serialization::un_any_int<K>, std::vector<boost::any>::const_iterator&, unsigned int)’:
  ../src/Multi_Array_Serialization.hpp:88:46: error: missing template arguments before ‘)’ token save_multi_array ( ar , var , version );
                                                                                                 ^
   ../src/Multi_Array_Serialization.hpp: In function ‘void boost::serialization::load_any(Archive&, boost::serialization::un_any_type<T>, boost::serialization::un_any_int<K>, std::vector<boost::any>::iterator, unsigned int)’:
   ../src/Multi_Array_Serialization.hpp:109:37: error: missing template arguments before ‘)’ token load_multi_array(ar, var, version);
                                 ^
```

Finally note that in the body of main I just initialize and use some different type of objects etc that I want to check if they are serialized correctly!
So, in more details this is my exact problem, I realize that I should change sth in the way I call the save_multi_array and load_multi_array template methods in the corresponding save_any and load_any template methods (in the line noted above) I am just not sure what. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue!

Comment: Please help us help you by giving the complete error message, including line number and give us a hint where in your code that line is, or create a minimal, complete, verifiable example that we can use to reproduce the error (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I hope the upgraded version of the question will help you understand things more properly! If anything else is needed pls let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in both your `load_any`function and in the `save_any` function. You intend to pass the integer `file_version` to `load_multi_array` and `save_multi_array`, but you write `version`. The compiler then thinks that you are referring to

```
template <class T> struct boost::serialization::version;
```

That template does need a template argument, that's why you get the error message.